# How to check if field with value None is stored in datastore or not stored at all?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let explain the problem.

We define some class DeleteMe and create on entity:

```
class DeleteMe(db.Model):
  a = db.FloatProperty()

DeleteMe(key_name = '1').put()
```

Now we can read it:

```
print DeleteMe.get_by_key_name('1').a
# = None
```

Now we change model to add new field

```
class DeleteMe(db.Model):
  a = db.FloatProperty()
  b = db.FloatProperty()
```

Now we can read it:

```
print DeleteMe.get_by_key_name('1').a
# = None and None in datastore
print DeleteMe.get_by_key_name('1').b
# = None but value b is not stored in datastore
```

How to distinguish a = None from b = None and get information that a is stored but b is not stored - it is important if you do query since.

```
DeleteMe.all().filter('a', None) # = 1 result
DeleteMe.all().filter('b', None) # = 0 result
```

Comment: You need to set a default value for the property and every entity needs to be rewritten once the property has been added to the model.

Comment: Yes but I want to determine what rewrite - not rewrite all entities since it not good on large data sets. Need some function to determine changes.

Comment: Its not possible to query for items that have no value, as there is no value in the index to query for.  How many items are you talking about?  THe only way would be to query for all the keys, then query for all the keys with a value.  Then rewrite all the keys from the first set that are not in the second set.

Comment: It is irrelevant to question - I am already explained that it is impossible to query in question - you repeat me. No matter how many records - it is not solution to remember each time about rewrite - it is error generating. Question is how to check if model is mirror image of entity or not.

Comment: Fair enough, though you did say it was important for querying.  Schema migration would normally be the time to update entities.  Fundamentally the underlying raw entity doesn't have the property.  So you need to examine that. You example uses `db` if you look at `_entity` attribute you can see if property in question actually exists for the specific entity.

Comment: If you use ndb you can examine `_values` attribute of the entity for the raw dictionary.

Comment: I think about _entity but it is undocumented and I afraid that I can write useless code which will not work in future. It is the best option as you suggest but it is not trusted.

Comment: Hey you want a solution.  As far as I know there is no other way of doing what you want.  The raw entity has to exist in the model entity.  The api could possibly change in the future however the db _entity has not changed since it was released in 2008.  Also db is not getting any new work, so you are going to likely to run into a deadend there before the `_entity` attribute goes away.

Comment: ndb and db use same API so you probably not know that both of them will run into deadend together. Whatever ndb is very bad idea becuase you will need rewrite thousand line of code - ndb gives you nothing special to promote it. Why you think that db is no changed recently since there is changes?

Comment: This is now a rat hole but I will bite, I don't agree with your statement "Whatever ndb is very bad idea becuase you will need rewrite thousand line of code - ndb gives you nothing special to promote it"  I have been developing for appengine since it was released, ndb solves a number of problems that db created (e.g reference properties), ndb has better support of async operations. Both of these a good reason to recommend it over db for anyone starting out.  Porting from db to ndb is not particularly hard, I have done that too.

Comment: You don't agree but it is not true that ndb solves problem with referenced properties - there is not such problem with db you which solved ndb both API has different method of achieving same.

"better support" - what does it mean? - typically nothing (better sometimes is illusion). I am not using async operation often since it is rare use it in transactions - rare use cases - I use it with db in less than 1/50 of cases.

Simple example can not update counter async and not wait on result since collision is possible even I use extreme sharding.

Comment: Transforming on 100 000-200 000 line of code using db is extremly hard and costly since it require high search/replace/refactor skills, high testing skills and a lost of time - belive me that is not easy at all.

ndb is good if you start for scratch but both ndb and db use same API so if db dies ndb dies too because of this reason.

Comment: I never said *you* should change, I just said you asked for a solution and I provided one for db and ndb.  No one else has suggested an alternative.  As for async, I use it a lot.  Mileage will vary.  As for reference properties in db if you fetch large numbers of entities and you de-reference the reference properties you need to jump through hoops with prefetching reference properties to be efficient.  You don't need to do that with ndb.  As for api death, you didn't want to use what I suggested as you said it was unsupported, use that approach or not or don't I don't really care.

Comment: db and ndb is currently supported together as far as it explained in documentation. Not sure if you use async a lot since it required rarely. Yes ndb give you caching and allow advanced hooking out of the box of put, get, require more coding in fact ... - it is designed by Guido to be more objective than db. You can do caching with db. It is not helpful for db programs until I will not start mirror usage of db and ndb what lead to clear code duplication - need have model in db and ndb to use both. As far I know ndb is independent part of gae but maybe wrong.